# Why do we need `*args` in decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, args

```
def pass_thru(func_to_decorate):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):  #1
        print("Function has been decorated.  Congratulations.")
        # Do whatever else you want here
        return func_to_decorate(*args, **kwargs)  #2
    return new_func


def print_args(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)


a = pass_thru(print_args)
a(1,2,3)

>> Function has been decorated.  Congratulations.
1
2
3
```

I understand that `*args` is used in #1 since it is a function declaration. But why is it necessary to write `*args` in #2 even if it not a function declaration?

Comment: You're bundling up the positional arguments into the tuple of args, then unbundling them back into separate arguments when you call the wrapped function.

Answer (score 1):

When used in function declaration, `*args` turn positional arguments into tuple:

```
def foo(a, *args):
    pass
foo(1, 2, 3)    #  a = 1, args = (2, 3)
```

When used in function call, `*args` expands tuple into positional arguments:

```
def bar(a, b, c):
    pass
args = (2, 3)
foo(1, *args)   # a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```

This is two opposite processes, so combining them allows to pass arbitary number of arguments to decorated function.

```
@pass_thru
def foo(a, b):
    pass
@pass_thru
def bar(a, b, c):
    pass

foo(1, 2)     # -> args = (1, 2) -> a = 1, b = 2
bar(1, 2, 3)  # -> args = (1, 2, 3) -> a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```